# Getting value of dropdownlist using Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

Guys I got a dropdownlist as

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedVatRate, Model.VatRate, new { @class = "form-control", onBlur = "pricingSectionVatDisplay()" })
```

In my function I want to access the value selected in the dropdownlist so as to use it as

```
function pricingSectionVatDisplay() {
        if ($("#selectedVatRate").val() == "0%" || "5%" || "20%") {

            $("#pricingConsumerVat").text($("#selectedVatRate").val());

            $("#pricingInnerCaseVat").text($("#selectedVatRate").val());

            $("#pricingOuterCaseVat").text($("#selectedVatRate").val());
        }
    }
```

However I cannot access the value of the dropdownlist.

How can I do so ?

Comment: What HTML code does `@Html.DropDownListFor` generate? Show it, please.

Comment: `$("#selectedVatRate").val() == "0%" || "5%" || "20%"` won't check what you wanted.

Comment: Use `$("#selectedVatRate").val() == "0%" || $("#selectedVatRate").val() == "5%" || $("#selectedVatRate").val() == "20%"`

Comment: better extract `$("#selectedVatRate").val()` into a variable.

Comment: Assign ID to control and then try same code.

Comment: While the if statement IS wrong I think he is asking about the getting the value from the drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

it is a invalid `if` condition

```
if ($("#selectedVatRate").val() == "0%" || "5%" || "20%") {
```

please try to change

```
if ($("#selectedVatRate").val() == "0%" || $("#selectedVatRate").val() == "5%" || $("#selectedVatRate").val() == "20%") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onBlur = "pricingVatDisplay(this)"
```

Then in your js function

```
function pricingVatDisplay(ddl) {
    var value = $(ddl).val();

    if (value == "0%" || value == "5%" || value == "20%") {
        ...
    }
}
```